# Dual Boot Windows XP and Windows 7 64 bit logging into domain

Tags: windows-server-2008

I dual boot my pc, but once I login using Win 7 64 bit to the Windows server 2008 domain I cannot login wiht my Windows XP 32 bit boot.  XP boot says domain cannot be found, previous to boot with Windows 7 login had no problems.

Comment: What have you check already?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have different computer names for each OS.